# Spring-mvc using async controllers

Tags: java, spring-mvc, asynchronous

I'm creating a spring-mvc restful app, and I'm questionning about performance when it gonna be on production.

I found this [link](https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/07/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-introducing-servlet-3-async-support) about async controllers, but I still have few questions. In general, what happens when 3 clients try to access a page?
Is this async or synchronous that is to say, **I)** client A will be processed, then B, and then C, like a waiting queue, or **II)** do they have a different and single thread each?

If **I)**, would I have to make all my controllers aync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requests are processed concurrently using a worker pool of threads.

No, you don't need to make anything async. You can get an advantage from them if you have long blocking requests, but unless you understand how and why, don't bother worrying about it.

Comment: Thanks. I can see different situations for async. Async methods are supposed to do actions in back while the user is not blocked, right?

Comment: Are you talking about asynchronous methods or asynchronous requests?

Comment: I mean asynchronous requests

Comment: They free up a worker thread while it's waiting for a long running operation (e.g. a database operation that takes a minute, or an external request to another system). The user will still be waiting for the actual response to that request.

Comment: Could u just give me a simple example? (when am I supposed to use an async request)